# How to mock a third-pary class with pytest & mock

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

my test code:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest
from journalwatcher.journal import read_for_test

@patch("systemd.journal.Reader")
def test_read(Reader):
    read_for_test(this_boot_only=True)
    Reader.this_boot.assert_called_once()
```

which is executed by pytest.

My to-be-tested code

```py
import systemd.journal

def read_for_test(this_boot_only=False):
    j = systemd.journal.Reader()
    if this_boot_only:
        j.this_boot()
```

Executing the code always gives the test error that `this_boot` was not called. Debugging reveals that `j` is a `MagicMock` instance, but a different one (`id` value) than `Reader`.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong here, but what?

Comment: Don't patch where you import from, patch where you import to. Best would be to import `Reader` directly and patch `to_be_tested_code.Reader`.

Comment: Because of how the descriptor protocol works, `Reader.this_boot` and `Reader().this_boot` are two different objects. (The former would be the actual function, the latter the return value of `Reader.this_boot.__get__`.)

Comment: (The mock object doesn't know that `Reader.this_boot.__get__()` would actually call `Reader.this_boot` in real life.)

Answer (score 0):

To help illustrate what was mentioned in the comments, what is meant by "to_be_tested" can also be seen as ***where*** you are testing. So, if that `systemd.journal.Reader` is what you want to mock, you are testing it through wherever you have the `read_for_test` method. From your example you are importing:

```
from journalwatcher.journal import read_for_test
```

So, whatever you want to mock within that context of what and where you are testing has to be mocked out as:

```
journalwatcher.journal.systemd.Reader
```

The main takeaway, again is to ensure that your mocking is done with respect to where and what you are testing. You can read more about patching in the documentation here:

[where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

So, what ***should*** work for you now is something along the lines of:

```
@patch("journalwatcher.journal.systemd.Reader")
def test_read(mock_reader):
    mock_reader.return_value = Mock()

    read_for_test(this_boot_only=True)

    mock_reader.return_value.this_boot.assert_called_once()
```

If you want to take it a step further, you can even instead pass `autospec=True` to your `@patch` decorator and this way it will actually hold the valid spec of the class so that you assert methods that actually exist and are being used properly. So, this should work as well:

[Info on autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing)

```
@patch("journalwatcher.journal.systemd.Reader", autospec=True)
def test_read(mock_reader):
    read_for_test(this_boot_only=True)

    mock_reader.return_value.this_boot.assert_called_once()
```